# How do I return a + 'day' using the date - today function?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Team,

I'm using this formula to get the # of days my financials are outstanding. I'm using the date, less today and it's returning a minus sign in my returned days.

I do need to know the difference between the date listed, vs todays date, but would like it to be a positive:
Z - Days = 'LSI DP_JP_HistorySummaryBySiteMaster'[Z Date]-TODAY()

Any ideas?

Comment: A future Z Date gives a positive difference and a past Z Date gives a negative difference. Are you saying you want both of these to be positive?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question. I ended up using an if statement to return the days in a positive number:

```
Z - date = if(today()>'LSI DP_JP_HistorySummaryBySiteMaster'[Z Date],today()-'LSI DP_JP_HistorySummaryBySiteMaster'[Z Date])
```